# Reclassify a categorical variable into another categorical variable?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I want to recategorize a categorical variable. I was using the `cut` function as below:

```
g <- mun %>% mutate(., regiao=cut(ufn, 
    breaks=c(ufn %in% c( "Acre", "Amapá", "Amazonas", "Pará", "Rondônia", "Roraima", "Tocantins"),
        ufn %in% c( "Alagoas", "Bahia", "Ceará"," Maranhão", "Paraíba", "Pernambuco", "Piauí", "Rio Grande do Norte", "Sergipe"),
        ufn %in% c("Goiás", "Mato Grosso", "Mato Grosso do Sul", "Distrito Federal"),
        ufn %in% c("Espírito Santo", "Minas Gerais", "Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo"), 
        ufn %in% c( "Paraná", "Santa Catarina", "Rio Grande do Sul") ), labels=c("Norte","Nordeste","Centro- Oeste","Sudeste","Sul")))
```

But as you must know, I need to declare a numeric value to use it, then I couldn't keep going on.

My intention is to make these states are reading as regions. Do you know how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one way:

```
cats <- setNames(list(c( "Acre", "Amapá", "Amazonas", "Pará", "Rondônia", "Roraima", "Tocantins"),
                      c( "Alagoas", "Bahia", "Ceará"," Maranhão", "Paraíba", "Pernambuco", "Piauí", "Rio Grande do Norte", "Sergipe"),
                      c("Goiás", "Mato Grosso", "Mato Grosso do Sul", "Distrito Federal"),
                      c("Espírito Santo", "Minas Gerais", "Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo"), 
                      c( "Paraná", "Santa Catarina", "Rio Grande do Sul")),
                 c("Norte","Nordeste","Centro- Oeste","Sudeste","Sul"))
# example data
var <- c("Acre","Mato Grosso","Rio de Janeiro","Ceará","Espírito Santo")
df  <- data.frame(x=1:5, var)

f <- function(x) names(cats)[sapply(cats, function(y) x %in% y)]
df$region <- as.factor(sapply(df$var,f))
df
#   x            var        region
# 1 1           Acre         Norte
# 2 2    Mato Grosso Centro- Oeste
# 3 3 Rio de Janeiro       Sudeste
# 4 4          Ceará      Nordeste
# 5 5 Espírito Santo       Sudeste
```